# How do I get a variable out of a completion block?

Tags: ios, objective-c, multithreading, macos

- (void)fetchLastMessageInChannel

{
          __weak id weakSelf = self;

```
    for (ANKChannel *channel in self.channelArray)
    {
            NSLog(@"channels %@",channel);

             NSLog(@"channel last message %@",channel.latestMessageID);

        [[ClientManager currentClient] fetchMessageWithID:channel.latestMessageID inChannel:channel
                                               completion:^(id responseObject, ANKAPIResponseMeta *meta, NSError *error)
         {
             NSLog(@"message object %@",responseObject);
             ANKMessage *message = responseObject;

             dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
                 [weakSelf populateTextViews:message.text];
             });

             NSLog(@"message text %@",message.text);

         }];

    }
```

}

-(void)populateTextViews:(NSString *)message
{

```
NSMutableArray *textViews = [@[] mutableCopy];

NSMutableAttributedString *postText = [[NSMutableAttributedString alloc] initWithString:message];
[postText addAttributes:@{
                          NSFontAttributeName : [UIFont preferredFontForTextStyle:UIFontTextStyleBody],
                          NSForegroundColorAttributeName : [UIColor darkTextColor]
                          }
                  range:NSMakeRange(0, postText.length)];

UITextView *postTextView = [[UITextView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(80, 30, kPostLabelMaxWidth, 44)];
postTextView.attributedText = postText;
postTextView.dataDetectorTypes = UIDataDetectorTypeAll;
postTextView.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
postTextView.editable = NO;
postTextView.scrollEnabled = NO;
postTextView.clipsToBounds = NO; // So it doesn't clip the text selector

CGRect textViewBounds = postTextView.bounds;
textViewBounds.origin = CGPointMake(80, 30);
textViewBounds.size.width = MAX(textViewBounds.size.width, kPostLabelMaxWidth);
textViewBounds.size.height = postTextView.contentSize.height;


postTextView.bounds = textViewBounds;

[postTextView sizeToFit]; // Reload the content size

[textViews addObject:postTextView];



self.channelTextViewArray = [textViews copy];
```

}

This is where I stand now as far as my methods go with the help I've received. The self.channelTextViewArray is returning nil and causing a crash because the populateTextViews(NSString*)message never gets called.

Any ideas?

Comment: of course it is not working, because there is a "little" issue with your logic: the information, you'd like to get _outside_ of the block's scope will available _after_ the `NSLog` runs _outside_ of the block. you just need to synchronise the threads for achieving what you want, but you should not block the main thread until the block finishes. probably, you will need to use different code pattern for it than you are already using.

Comment: I'm a self taught programmer with only 8 months experience so I don't know everything, but I appreciate the help. Any suggestions for the code pattern your talking about?

Comment: send me the link of the source code via `GitHub` or `Bitbucket` and I will take a look on it.

Answer (score 1):

If `ClientManager` call is async, the `populateTextViews` method will complete before the async call returns, which is why you can't use the value set in its completion block.

Either put...

```
NSMutableAttributedString *postText = [[NSMutableAttributedString alloc] initWithString:messageText];
```

...inside the completion block, or call out to a method inside the completion block once you have the messageText. In doing that you will not have to declare the __block variable either.

If there will be a UI update, make sure that happens on the main thread.

**EDIT**

This the basic idea, but I'm guessing you're updating more than one text view so you may need to change the signatures around. If you get the basic idea -- calling an async method doesn't interrupt the flow of your code (basically it says "do this when you have a chance, possibly on another thread"). That's the reason you have a completion block -- it's a place in your code where you know that the async method you called has completed.

If what's inside the block isn't getting called at all, make sure that `self.channelArray` has values, and look at what `fetchMessageWithID` does if something goes wrong.

```
- (void)populateTextViews 
{
    __weak id weakSelf = self;
    for (ANKChannel *channel in self.channelArray)
    {    
        [[ClientManager currentClient] fetchMessageWithID:channel.latestMessageID inChannel:channel
                                               completion:^(id responseObject, ANKAPIResponseMeta *meta, NSError *error)
         {
             NSLog(@"message object %@",responseObject);
             ANKMessage *message = responseObject;
             dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
                 [weakSelf updateTextView:message.text];
             });        
         }];
    }
}

- (void)updateTextView:(NSString *)message
{
    // Make an attributed string from the post text content
    NSMutableAttributedString *postText = [[NSMutableAttributedString alloc] initWithString:messageText];
    self.textView.attributedText = postText;
}
```

Comment: Ok i'll give this a try.

Comment: I called out to another method inside the block, but when I put up breakpoints, what's inside the block doesn't get called anymore. I did something like this in the block.... [self populateTextViewWithString:messageText];

Comment: Editing answer to see if it helps. One moment.

Comment: Just got back home, will try this asap. Thanks so much for the help everyone

Comment: edited my orignal question with my updated code. Still getting a crash  because the textViewArray returns nil. My method of populating textviews never gets called inside the completion block.

Comment: Does anything inside the completion block get called? Can you check on the value of weakSelf inside the completion block (if the object that did the call went out of scope it may be released and then weakSelf will be nil).

Comment: Nothing in the block gets called. I set up a bunch of breakpoints and it goes from the two nslogs under the for in, to the current client call, then right back to the nslogs. Don't know why it's not getting inside the completion block.

Comment: I'm not familiar with '[ClientManager currentClient]' but make sure it's non-nil, make sure that it calls its completion block no matter what happens, and make sure you are giving the operation time to complete.